# Overlay graph in tkinter

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I am making an embeded matplotlib graph GUI program. 
[image]

I want to make overlaid graphs in upper graph window when users click the "Update" button.

But, There is no response when I click "Update" button.

I am using Spyder Python 3.6 Version.

Below is what I wrote.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import csv
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

import matplotlib as plt
plt.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib import style


class Analysis_app(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "SIM Analyser")


        right_f = tk.Frame(self)
        right_f.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)


        self.entry1 = ttk.Entry(right_f).pack()
        self.entry2 = ttk.Entry(right_f).pack()
        self.entry3 = ttk.Entry(right_f).pack()
        self.entry4 = ttk.Entry(right_f).pack()
        self.entry5 = ttk.Entry(right_f).pack()

        Button1 = ttk.Button(right_f, text='Update', command=self.plot).pack(side=tk.BOTTOM)


        self.left_f = tk.Frame(self)
        self.left_f.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        f = Figure(figsize=(10,6), dpi=100)
        self.upplot = f.add_subplot(211)
        self.botplot = f.add_subplot(212)


        a =self.upplot
        a.clear()
        a.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])


        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.show()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)


        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        self.mainloop()

   def plot(self):

        a =self.upplot
        a.clear()
        a.plot([1,2,3],[5,2,5])
```

Comment: BTW: `Button1 = Button(...).pack()` will assign None to `Button1` because `pack()` returns `None`, not widget. If you don't need access button later then you can do without `Button1` -> `Button(...).pack()`

Comment: Ok. I modified. Thanks~! :)

Comment: BTW: Because you use Python3 so you can use `super().__init__()` instead of `tk.Tk.__init__(self)`. Because `Analysis_app` inherits from `tk.Tk` so you can use `self.wm_title("SIM Analyser")` instead of `tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "SIM Analyser")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get no response because the canvas is not redrawn after changing the content of the plot.

The solution is to replace `canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)` by `self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)` so that you can redraw the canvas in `self.plot`:

```
def plot(self):
    a = self.upplot
    a.clear()
    a.plot([1,2,3],[5,2,5])
    self.canvas.draw_idle()
```

And then you should see the change after clicking on the update button.

Comment: Using `draw_idle()` is more GUI friendly than `draw()`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest thanks for the information, I was not aware of the existence of `draw_idle()`. I have edited my answer.